# Google spreadsheets IF-ELSE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to add specific amount of time to a date.

I have a date (german formatting/ dd.mm.yy) in C2. Then I have a duration in D2, which is either in years or month. (1 year, 2 years or 1 month, 2 months, ...)

In G2 I want the date from C2 + the value from D2, and on top the month rounded up to the 1st of the following month.

I already tried a nested IF function
`=IF(FIND("month";D2); EDATE(DATE((RIGHT(C2;2));MID(C2;4;2)+(LEFT(D2;FIND(" ";D2)-1));"01");1); IF(FIND("year";D2);EDATE(DATE((RIGHT(C2;2)+(LEFT(D2;FIND(" ";D2)-1)));MID(C2;4;2);"01");1);""))`

But that only works if there are X month(s) in D2. If there are X year(s) then I get #VALUE! and an error that tells me that "FIND" cannot find "month" in "2 years".

Comment: Doing string matching on a text cell to extract a numerical component, then using it as a dynamically positional argument to another formula is not something that the expression engine in Sheets was really designed for. I'd suggest making two temporary columns. In one, just extract the number from the duration field. In the other, add your text search conditional to return true/1 if duration is a month, and 0/false if it is a year. Then update your formula in G2 to reference the temporary columns. Once that is working, in-line the logic back into G2.

Comment: Could you please give some examples, and the output you want ?

Comment: Example: C2 is 15.01.20 and D2 is 10 month, then G2 should show 01.12.20. Or C2 is 15.01.20 and D2 is 2 years, then G2 should be 01.02.22 - so ADD D2 and then round up to the follwing months 1st.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in G2:

```
=lambda(splitdate;addtime;
lambda(month;year;addamnt;addunit;
date(100+year+(regexmatch(addunit;"year")*addamnt);month+(regexmatch(addunit;"month")*addamnt)+1;1))(
index(splitdate;;2);index(splitdate;;3);index(addtime;;1);index(addtime;;2)))(
split(C2;".");split(D2;" "))
```

N.B. 1: The output is in dd/mm/yyyy format; use a custom number format to convert this back into dd/mm/yy for display.
N.B. 2: I've assumed that you want to round the result to the first day of the next month even if the date in D2 is the first day of a month; it's a fairly simple modification if this isn't what you want to do.

Comment: are you sure that this is compatible with google spreadsheets? I get a parsing error when inserting it.

Comment: Try now - I've changed all the argument separators to semicolons (European style) instead of the original commas (US/UK style)

Comment: thats what I thought too, so I had already changed the commas to ; - but still #ERROR! edit: you forgot to change one comma ;)

Comment: Oops - I've edited the answer to change the final comma to a semicolon as well...